# Showing the Naturality of Two (Isomorphic) Left Adjoints

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, natural-transformations

From pg. 85 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]

**Problem:** I understand everything except the red underlined portion.

To introduce some notation, let $h: x \rightarrow x'$ in $X$. Then showing that $\theta$ is natural is tantamount to showing that

$$
F'h \circ \theta_x = \theta_{x'} \circ Fh
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last equation is an equality between two arrows $Fx\to F'x'$. Thus it is enough to check that their images under the bijection $A(Fx,F'x')\to X(x,GF'x')$ are equal. You know (for example from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334957/trouble-showing-the-naturality-of-an-adjunction-induced-by-langle-f-g-eta?rq=1)) that this bijection is given by $f\mapsto G(f)\circ \eta_x$, so it is enough to check that :
\begin{align}G(F'h\circ \theta_x)\circ \eta_x & = GF'h\circ G\theta_x\circ \eta_x \\ & = GF'h\circ \eta_x'\\ & = \eta_{x'}'\circ h \\ & = G\theta_{x'}\circ \eta_{x'}\circ h \\ & = G\theta_{x'}\circ GFh\circ \eta_x \\ & = G(\theta_{x'}\circ Fh)\circ \eta_x.\end{align}